# c++ print Hexadecimal with int word, ostream &os

Tags: c++, printing, hex

I am new to stack overflow.

I am having trouble figuring out how to complete my code for this assignment. Here are the instructions for the assignment.

> The function writes the hexadecimal representation of word to output stream os. The function must use bit operations (using the hex manipulator is not allowed).

This is what I have so far.

```
extern const int N = sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT; 

void printHexadecimal(int word, ostream& os)
{
    for (i = (N - 1)/4*4; i >= 0; i-= 4)
    {
        getBit () 
    }
}
```

Comment: As a hint the general idea is to shift 4 bits (1 hex digit) at a time into another variable, and then convert that to a character (like '3' or 'A'). Then join all the characters to make a string representing the hex number. People here will not write the code, but we will help you if you make a serious attempt.

Comment: What you probably need is the proper usage of operators `&` and `>>`. Here is a doc. to start with: [Bitwise logic operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Bitwise_logic_operators).

Comment: Thank you for the help and the link.